# How to add const qualifier to vector<>::pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, pointers, constants

I'm trying to pass a const pointer to an element of a `std::vector` to a function, but I can't seem to get the function's signature right. I must be missing something trivial here, but I'm confused.

This is the minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class Image { void* ptr; };

using ImageConstRefArray = std::vector< std::reference_wrapper< Image const >>;

template< typename T = void, typename... OtherTs >
void TestDataType( const ImageConstRefArray::pointer images ) {
   // stuff.
   TestDataType< OtherTs... >( images + 1 );
}
template<>
inline void TestDataType<>( const ImageConstRefArray::pointer /*images*/ ) {} // End of iteration

template< typename... Types >
void Function( ImageConstRefArray const& images ) {
   TestDataType< Types... >( images.data() );
}

int main() {
   Image img1, img2;
   ImageConstRefArray array{ img1, img2 };
   Function( array );
}
```

This is GCC's (5.4) error message:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Function(const ImageConstRefArray&) [with Types = {}; ImageConstRefArray = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const Image> >]’:
test.cpp:24:20:   required from here
test.cpp:18:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘TestDataType(const std::reference_wrapper<const Image>*)’
    TestDataType< Types... >( images.data() );
                            ^
test.cpp:9:6: note: candidate: template<class T, class ... OtherTs> void TestDataType(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const Image> >::pointer)
 void TestDataType( const ImageConstRefArray::pointer images ) {
      ^
test.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:18:41: note:   cannot convert ‘(& images)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::data<std::reference_wrapper<const Image>, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<const Image> > >()’ (type ‘const std::reference_wrapper<const Image>*’) to type ‘std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const Image> >::pointer {aka std::reference_wrapper<const Image>*}’
    TestDataType< Types... >( images.data() );
```

So basically it's trying to put a `const std::reference_wrapper<const Image>*` into a `std::reference_wrapper<const Image>*`. The function's signature has `const ImageConstRefArray::pointer` as the parameter. If that `const` doesn't make the pointer a const pointer, then how do I write the function signature? Is the only solution to write out `const std::reference_wrapper<const Image>*`? That solves the issue, but I'd rather write it in terms of `ImageConstRefArray`.

Comment: `const ImageConstRefArray::value_type *` or `ImageConstRefArray::const_pointer`.

Comment: @AnT Doh! It's really that trivial. C++ is making me crazy! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `const ImageConstRefArray::pointer`, `const` is qualifed on the pointer itself, so it'll be `std::reference_wrapper<const Image>* const` (`const` pointer to non-const), but not `std::reference_wrapper<const Image> const *` (non-const pointer to `const`). (Note the different position of `const`.)

You should use [`std::vector::const_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types) instead, which will give you the type of pointer to `const T`. e.g.

```
template< typename T = void, typename... OtherTs >
void TestDataType( ImageConstRefArray::const_pointer images ) {
   // stuff.
   TestDataType< OtherTs... >( images + 1 );
}
template<>
inline void TestDataType<>( ImageConstRefArray::const_pointer /*images*/ ) {} // End of iteration
```

Comment: But why, if `vector::pointer` is `vector::value_type *`, doesn't `const vector::pointer` translate to `const vector::value_type *`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Answer revised.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see that. And it sort of makes sense. Funny how you think you understand a language but it keeps coming back with unexpected things. :/

Comment: @CrisLuengo You just need to consider it *grammatically*, not just "textual substitution" (as macro does).

Comment: @cris you also need to stop writing `const` on the left; no good comes of that.

Comment: @Yakk I absolutely agree with you. It's GCC that moves the `const` to the left in its error messages.

Comment: @cris I mean here: `const ImageConstRefArray::pointer` -- put on the right, no confusion.

Comment: @Yakk `pointer const` is the same as `value_type * const`. I needed `value_type const*`. This is why I put the `const` on the left. But of course it didn't help, as @songyuanyao explained. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Which is my point.  **never ever** put `const` on the **left**.  It is misleading and doesn't do what you think it does unless you get lucky.  You want `value_type const*`, with `const` on the *right* of `value_type`.  `const value_type*` is a bad idea to even think about.  When it works, it works like a similar "const on the right", and when it doesn't, you are bamboozled.